# Some code pieces randomly exit the current method

Tags: vb.net, clr

This is a really strange error I have been getting sometimes with SOME libraries (be it included in the framework or not).

For example, this time I got it with LuaInterface doing this:

```
//' s = string to existing file path
lua.DoFile(s)
Dim func = lua.GetFunction("ohai_regex()")
Dim ret = func.Call() 'doesnt do anything
//' file s contains function ohai()
MessageBox.Show("Geronimo!") 'NEVER gets reached
```

I'd expect the func.Call() to return an exception if something is up, or do anything to error out, but here it just murders my method which returns instantly! The same stuff here is also in a loop, which doesn't get any more iterations, it just stops executing this function and continues running the program.

This has been occuring to me a few times now. I don't remember the other times though.

(Maybe the LuaInterface code I'm using up here is wrong, but that's not really my point...)

Comment: surround with `try catch`, probably you getting exception in that call

Comment: @Reniuz That actually worked... Last time I had the same issue it didn't work. So maybe theres a exception sneaking by the "normal" CLR exception handler but not my own `try catch` mechanism. Should that actually happen in the clr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible reasons:

- The code *does* actually throw an exception, and you catch it and ignore it at some other level.
- The code in the library is broken, so that it eats up its own return address from the stack, and uses the return address of your method when it returns.

Comment: I can actually try-catch the error, but not using the debugging mechanisms in Visual Studio. Should the "eats up its own return address" actually be possible to happen in the CLR? Crazy... Maybe it has something to do with native code?

Comment: @sinni800: Broken code like that normally doesn't occur in managed code. I have experienced it when I have created code dynamically from IL code.

Comment: Hmm, okay. But LuaInterface for example calls a native library, lua51.dll